# Analysing memory leaks with DevPartner

Tags: .net, winforms, memory-leaks, devpartner

We are using DevPartner to analyse memory leaks in our application.

I got a set of analysis reports after memory leak analysis using DevPartner. Actually, I am not aware of how to generate reports.

Anyway, now I started analysing the reports. They are showing some methods and objects with the % of memory leaked.

Actually, we ran this sometime back and as a part of the analysis we fixed some leaks, like suppose one private object was declared in a method and we disposed of that object after use at the end of the method.

Now again when we run DevPartner, it is showing the same object in the report. I am not sure why it is showing the same object again.

Similarly, one of our classes is implementing IDisposable interface, and in the `Dispose()` method we are either clearing the object or disposing of the object. Now also the object is showing as memory leaked by DevPartner.

Is anyone aware of how DevPartner analyses memory leaks in an application?

Thanks.

Comment: Just as a question apart: are you using Serialization / Deserialization ?

Comment: @Laurent : Sorry i didnt get you..

Comment: Nothing to do with devpartner itself. I just wonder if your application uses the .NET Serializer: this .NET tool it is plagged by a memory leak which is very hard to track down. So I mention this in the case of.

Comment: @Laurent : No we are not using..